# Bubble sort of structures using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, bubble-sort

I want to sort an array of structures using the bubble sort algorithm and pointers in C. 
I have a cars structure:

```
typedef struct{
    char model[30];
    int hp;
    int price;
}cars;
```

and I allocate memory for 12 items:

```
cars *pointer = (cars*)malloc(12*sizeof(cars));
```

and read data from file:

```
for (i = 0; i <number ; i++) {
    fscanf(file, "%s %i %i\n", (pointer+i)->model, &(pointer+i)->hp, &(pointer+i)->price);
}
```

I pass pointer `ptr` to `bubbleSort` function:

```
bubbleSort(pointer, number);
```

Here is my `bubbleSort` function:

```
void bubbleSort(cars *x, int size) {
    int i, j;
    for (i=0;i<size-1;i++) {
    int swapped = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; j++) {
        if ( (x+i)->hp > (x+j+1)->hp ) {
            cars *temp = (x+j+1);
            x[j+1] = x[j];
            x[j] = *temp;
            swapped = 1;
        }
    }
        if (!swapped) {
        //return;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to swap items using pointers.

Comment: try `cars *temp = (x+j+1);` change to `cars temp = x[j+1];`..`x[j] = temp;`

Comment: also `if ( (x+i)->hp > (x+j+1)->hp ) {` --> `if ( (x+j)->hp > (x+j+1)->hp ) {`

Comment: There's never a need to type cast the return of malloc.  That's a c++ thing.  Just use `cars *pointer = malloc(12*sizeof(cars));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider the following solution for sorting function:

```
void bubbleSort(cars *x, int size) 
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size-1-i; j++) 
        {
            if ( x[j].hp > x[j+1].hp ) 
            {
               cars temp = x[j+1];
               x[j+1] = x[j];
               x[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem was in the data swap part

Comment: Now, after the correction you indicates me, also the mine is a correct solution, a little bit different!

Comment: Your solution will be different, if you not just copy examples. And of course, there are infinite number of different solutions to the same problemю Good luck!

Comment: @VolAnd, this may be considered standard coding! I don't think Dogbert it saying to be discovered nothing and if you refers to me see at the time of the reply and note that I wrote the reply before Dogbert, but with some errors that I've corrected!

Answer (score 0):

```
void bubbleSort(cars *x, int size)
{
        int i, j;
        cars temp;

        for (i=0;i<size-1;i++) {
            for (j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
                if ( (x+i)->hp > (x+j)->hp ) {
                    temp = x[j];
                    x[j] = x[i];
                    x[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is a reply to a comment under this code; it demonstrates that the sort that I suggest swaps less ... :) Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int x;
    int hp;
} cars;

int swaps;

void bubbleSortB(cars *x, int size)
{
        int i, j;
        cars temp;

        for (i=0;i<size-1;i++) {
            for (j = i+1; j < size; j++) {
                if ( (x+i)->hp > (x+j)->hp ) {
                    temp = x[j];
                    x[j] = x[i];
                    x[i] = temp;
                    swaps++;
                }
            }
        }
}

void bubbleSortA(cars *x, int size)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size-1-i; j++)
        {
            if ( x[j].hp > x[j+1].hp )
            {
               cars temp = x[j+1];
               x[j+1] = x[j];
               x[j] = temp;
               swaps++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;

    cars x[10]={ {1,4},{1,8},{1,12},{1,6},{1,5},{1,4},{1,8},{1,12},{1,6},{1,5} };
    cars y[10]={ {1,4},{1,8},{1,12},{1,6},{1,5},{1,4},{1,8},{1,12},{1,6},{1,5} };

    swaps=0;
    bubbleSortA(x,10);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",x[i].hp);
    printf("- swaps %d\n",swaps);

    swaps=0;
    bubbleSortB(y,10);  //My sort
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",y[i].hp);
    printf("- swaps %d\n",swaps);

}
```

Comment: You're not dereferencing `(x+j)`, and are assigning a pointer-to-struct to a a struct.

Comment: ... Today I'm drunk ... :) Now all should be correct!

Comment: This is not the usual bubble sort algorithm which operates on "pair[s] of adjacent items". It's more similar to selection sort with a lot of useless swaps.

Comment: @undur_gongor, I executed a little test on the two sort methods (mine and DogBert)! The result is the same, but mine swaps less! ... :) I added the test in the code above because it doesn't fits inside a comment

Comment: Maybe. Still it's not bubble sort. If performance is important, both bubble sort and selection sort are out.

Comment: I use always qsort that is in the libraries!!! But mine is an optimization of bubble-sort!

Answer (score -1):

Use a swap function like this:

```
#define TYPE <your type>
void swap(TYPE *a, TYPE *b){
        TYPE *temp = (TYPE*)malloc(sizeof(TYPE));
        *temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = *temp;
        free(temp);
}
```

Or this one, without malloc:

```
void swap(TYPE *a, TYPE *b){
        TYPE temp;
        temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
}
```

Comment: No no no. If the values are the same, you zero out the data. It's not a good trick to use. Also, it won't work like you think it will with structs. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/182037/is-this-xor-value-swap-algorithm-still-in-use-or-useful

Comment: The value to swap is not an integer, but a structure! :)

Comment: @Dogbert for sorting, why would the values be swapped if they were the same?  This seems like dogma, but I'll edit the answer anyway...

Comment: This solution runs only with integer types such as char, int, long, but not with STRUCTURES!!!

Comment: Why use `malloc` (which might fail) if you can just create the `TYPE` variable directly (without pointer indirection)?

Comment: @undur_gongor hmm... I guess that would be better, since there's just one temp variable.  I'll add in an alternate version of the function.

Comment: You have changed the code! I'm saying you that you can't make XOR between two structures!

Comment: your new solution doesn't apport advantages and use an useless malloc, where the in-line swap is the better and fastest solution!

Comment: Maybe so, but using a separate function makes it more readable!  That is just my personal preference, though!